# Wordpress alphabetical index

Tags: wordpress, post, hyperlink, alphabetical

I have a question.
How can do an alphabetical index with links without plugin ?
Example :  `A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z`

If a character contains posts, it will be a link.
Else it will text.

Anyone can help me ?

Update : Or something like this http://dribbble.com/tags

Answer (score 0):

You could write a few lines of code to query the database and do a like search on the post titles. The below is not formatted for a WP query, but it should give you a good idea:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   wp_posts
WHERE  post_title LIKE 'a%';
```

If the count is greater than 0, you know there are posts and you can add a hyperlink to the letter.